# JavaScript / jQuery access to newly loaded ajax data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a website like facebook. Every 10 seconds it checks posts to see if any new comments should be loaded. The code sort of looks like this:

```
<div id="profile_entry_1">
  <div id="posttext_id1">Woot woot!</div>
  <div id="comment_id15" class="checkForNewComments">This is the 15th comment in the database</comment>
  <div id="more_wall_comments_div_1"></div>
</div>
<div id="profile_entry_2">
  <div id="posttext_id2">Woot woot!</div>
  <div id="comment_id16">This is the 16th comment in the database</comment>
  <div id="comment_id17">This is the 17th comment in the database</comment>
  <div id="comment_id18" class="checkForNewComments">This is the 18th comment in the database</comment>
  <div id="more_wall_comments_div_2"></div>
</div>
```

So above there are two posts, the first two in the database, with comments on each. When the page first loads the PHP will look for the very last comment and assign it a certain class.

It's assigned a class of "checkForNewComments" so my JavaScript can grab its comment_id ID.

It sends that ID through to a new page to look for comments on that post that have a greater value, and it will load them through an Ajax call in jSon format. I parse it, and .append() it to the "newComments" section.

So, if the code finds a new comment it will strip the posts' class of "checkForNewComments"

```
<div id="profile_entry_2">
  <div id="posttext_id2">Woot woot!</div>
  <div id="comment_id16">This is the 16th comment in the database</comment>
  <div id="comment_id17">This is the 17th comment in the database</comment>
  <div id="comment_id18">This is the 18th comment in the database</comment>
  <div id="more_wall_comments_div_2"></div>
</div>
```

The post it loads, say, comment_id19 will now have the class of "checkForNewComments", so in 10 seconds when it looks for new comments it will look for a comment greater than 19.

Here's the trouble, JavaScript cannot access newly loaded DIV and CLASS information.

How do I go about this?

---

### Here is my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadedComments = true;
function loadComRefresh(timeoutPeriod){ setTimeout("loadNewComs();",timeoutPeriod); }
function loadNewComs(){
  if (loadedComments == true){
    loadedComments = false;
    var loadComString = "";
    $('.loadNewComs').each(function() {
    comLoad = this.id.substr(14);
    testD = $("#more_wall_comments_div_" + comLoad).find(".commentDivID").attr("id");
    if (testD != undefined){
      addSub = ":"+ testD +"";
    } else { addSub = ""; }
    loadComString = loadComString + comLoad + addSub + ",";
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: '../members/more_wall_comments_json.php',
    data: "loadComString=" + loadComString,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) { 
      loadedComments = true; 
      if (data != null){
        for(var i=0; i<data.loadComs.length;i++) {
          $("#postnewcomment" + data.loadComs[i].id).html(data.loadComs[i].script);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  loadComRefresh(10000);
}
</script>
<body onLoad="loadComRefresh(10000);">
```

---

### Here is my PHP/HTML of the document

```
<?php
echo '
<div id="profile_entry_'. $recent_id .'" class="loadNewComs" '. $delete_mouse_over .'>
  <table style="width:'. $table_width .'">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:50px;height:50px;padding:5px;vertical-align:top;">
        <a href="'. $extralink .'viewmember.php?id='. $to_id .'"><img src="'. getMemberThumbnail($to_id) .'" style="width:50px;height:50px;display:block;" alt="" /></a>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:5px 5px 5px 0;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
        <a href="'. $extralink .'viewmember.php?id='. $to_id .'">'. getName($to_id) .'</a>
        <div style="margin:2px 0 0 0;">'. getEmoticon(tagUserLinks(breakUp($change))) .'</div>'
        <div id="more_wall_comments_div_'. $recent_id .'">';

$array = array();
$q = mysql_query("SELECT t1.id_id,t1.to_id,t1.from_id,t1.message_id,t1.like_id,t1.date_id,t1.mobile_id,t1.mobiletype_id,t2.user_id,t2.avatar FROM status_comments AS t1 LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.from_id = t2.id_id WHERE recent_id='$recent_id'") or die ('here!');
$q_count = mysql_num_rows($q);
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){ 
  $that_count = $that_count + 1;
  $comment_id = $r['id_id'];
  $to_id = $r['to_id'];
  $from_id2 = $r['from_id'];
  $message_id = $r['message_id'];
  $like = $r['like_id'];
  $date = $r['date_id'];
  $mobile = $r['mobile_id'];
  $mobiletype = $r['mobiletype_id'];
  $fromname_id = $r['user_id'];
  $thumbnail = '../media/members/thumbs/'. $r['avatar'];
  $array[$comment_id]  = array($comment_id,$to_id,$from_id2,$message_id,$like,$date,$mobile,$mobiletype,$fromname_id,$thumbnail);
}

krsort($array);
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 3, true);
ksort($array);


if ($q_count > 0) {
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {  
    $that_count = $that_count + 1;
    $comment_id = $value[0];
    $to_id = $value[1];
    $from_id2 = $value[2];
    $message_id = $value[3];
    $like = $value[4];
    $roughdate = $value[5];
    $mobile = $value[6];
    $mobiletype = $value[7];
    $fromname_id = $value[8];
    $thumbnail = $value[9];


    if ($that_count == 1 AND $recentlikecount == 0 AND $recentdislikecount == 0 AND $comments_topped != 'true') {
      echo '
          <div id="'. $comment_id .'" class="commentDivID" style="width:'. $commentsize .';" '. $delete_mouse_over_comment .'>
            <div style="width:'. $commentsize .';height:11px;background-image:url(../lib/images/comment_top.gif);"></div>
            <table style="width:'. $commentsize .';background-color:#'. $_SESSION['BGCOLOR'] .';border-bottom:1px solid #ccd4d8;">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:35px;height:35px;padding:5px;vertical-align:top;">
                  <a href="'. $extralink .'viewmember.php?id='. $from_id2 .'"><img src="'. $thumbnail .'" style="width:35px;height:35px;display:block;" /></a>
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px 5px 5px 0;vertical-align:top;">
                  <a href="'. $extralink .'viewmember.php?id='. $from_id2 .'">'. $fromname_id .'</a> '. getEmoticon(tagUserLinks(breakUp($message_id))) .'<br /> 
                  '. $mobile .' <span id="time'. $comment_id .'" name="'. $roughdate .'" class="loadTime">'. roughDate($roughdate) .'</span></span> '. $like_link .'
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>';
  }
}
echo '  </div>';
```

Now I didn't put the code in here, but the last comment is assigned the class="commentDivID" , not every comment.

When the javascript does a call and finds a new comment to load it will strip the last comment of the class="commentDivID" and place it in the new comment that is loaded, but javascript can't access newly loaded items so it's no longer able to find the class="commentDivID"

Comment: Are you actually loading HTML or JSON? Because your `.ajax` call specifies JSON, but your description makes it sound like HTML. If it's HTML, you should be able to use the `load` method.

Comment: It's json format, an array, but has HTML in it as the payload, exactly how Facebook does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've done this:

```
$("#postnewcomment" + data.loadComs[i].id).html(data.loadComs[i].script);
```

You should be able to select anything in the added HTML starting with the id you used, for example:

```
$("#postnewcomment" + data.loadComs[i].id + " div")
```

To select divs in the newly added content.

Comment: @DerekB: Yes, it was just missing it's buddy. Now it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the newest comment as a global javascript variable (before the function call). Once your ajax call finished updating the newest comment, update the counter for the newest comment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - it was stupid.

I was appending the data to a new DIV, not the one I was looking through for the specific class selector, so if course the javascript couldn't find the div - it wasn't where it should have been.

Thank you all for your help!